# This method program is acting wild.....need assistance please

Tags: java, methods

Ok so this java program I'm working on is supposed to compute an investment value over the course of 30 years. It asks the user where their starting investment is and the percentage rate (in the form of decimals). I thought I had it all figured out but my program is returning some ridiculous values. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what I did wrong?

These are the sample outputs provided to me

What is the amount invested? 1000

What is the annual interest rate? .09

```
Years   Future Value
-----   ------------
1       $1093.81
2       $1196.41
...
29      $13467.25
30      $14730.58
```

my output is returning values in billions and trillions of dollars...just crazy stuff. The formula I have been provided with is

```
futureValue = investmentAmmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)^numberOfYears*12
```

here is the code for my program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import java.util.Locale;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 public class InvestmentValue
 {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

         double investmentAmmnt;
         // monthly interest rate
         double mri; 
         int years;

         System.out.print("What is the ammount invested? ");
         investmentAmmnt = input.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("What is the annual interest rate? ");
         mri = input.nextDouble();

         futureInvestmentValue(investmentAmmnt, mri, 30);
         }

         public static double futureInvestmentValue(double investmentAmmnt, double mri, int years)
         {
            NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

            System.out.println("The amount invested: " + (df.format(investmentAmmnt)));
            System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + mri);
            System.out.println("Years \t \t Future Value");
            for (int i = 1; i <= years * 12; i++){
               investmentAmmnt = investmentAmmnt * Math.pow(1 + (mri / 12),(years * 12));
            if (i % 12 == 0){
               System.out.println(i / 12 + "\t\t" + (df.format(investmentAmmnt)));
               }
               }
            return investmentAmmnt;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure your formula is correct?

Comment: @neito, if you're frustrated by the down-votes I don't blame you. I think people overreacted to the "what's wrong with my code" nature of your question. It's clear you put work into solving it, and you did well to post a complete runnable program demonstrating the problem and also very well by posting the expected output. Anyway, looks like you got some good answers --- good luck!

Comment: One thing that will help is indenting your code properly; most editors have a "reformat" command that will do this for you. It's difficult to see where methods and other blocks begin and end here.

Comment: @jas thanks and yeah it was nice to see that at least some people were willing to help instead of acting like a pack of vultures. I think some of you have been staring at a computer screen for too long and need to go outside for some fresh air.

Comment: @neito Saying "I think that these comments were unnecessarily rude" is potentially justified. Making rude comments of your own isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it works:

```
  public static double futureInvestmentValue(final double investmentAmmnt, double mri, int years)
  {
    NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    double amount = investmentAmmnt;

    System.out.println("The amount invested: " + (df.format(investmentAmmnt)));
    System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + mri);
    System.out.println("Years \t \t Future Value");
    for (int i = 1; i <= years ; i++){
      amount = investmentAmmnt * Math.pow(1 + (mri /100),(i ));
    System.out.println(i  + "\t\t" + (df.format(amount)));
    }
    return amount;
  }
```

The problems are many with your code...

1. Your Increasing the amount with Math.pow() in a loop - that's why it goes wild.
2. Your loop iterates over years * 12 (months?)
3. Your doing wild *12 and /12 calculations you don't need.

--> output

`Years       Future Value
1       $1,030.00
2       $1,060.90
3       $1,092.73
4       $1,125.51
5       $1,159.27
6       $1,194.05
7       $1,229.87
8       $1,266.77
9       $1,304.77
10      $1,343.92
11      $1,384.23
12      $1,425.76
13      $1,468.53
14      $1,512.59
15      $1,557.97
16      $1,604.71
17      $1,652.85
18      $1,702.43
19      $1,753.51
20      $1,806.11
21      $1,860.29
22      $1,916.10
23      $1,973.59
24      $2,032.79
25      $2,093.78
26      $2,156.59
27      $2,221.29
28      $2,287.93
29      $2,356.57
30      $2,427.26`

Comment: ok, I can see what I did wrong now. I took it too literally I think.

Comment: @neito, if you change the line in the for loop to `amount = investmentAmmnt * Math.pow(1 + (mri / 12),(i * 12));` you'll get `$14,730.58` at year 30, matching your expected output. I'm not saying @Alexander is wrong --- maybe this output is more correct than the expected, but FYI.

Comment: yes, I was able to get that part thanks to @Alexander help. Thank you as well for providing further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the formula `futureValue = investmentAmmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)^numberOfYears*12` calculates the value of the investment for any amount of years in the future. The problem is that you for loop is calculating more than it needs to. That formula only needs to be done once. Your function futureInvestmentValue should not have a for loop.